# Hyperledger electricity consumption

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Do you have any estimate about power consumption of hyperledger-fabric? They use a specific consensus protocol, I wanted to have an estimate about its power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Private Blockchain Platforms like Hyperledger Fabric does not run on Proof of Work consensus that is power hungry.

Hyperledger Fabric currently runs on Kafka consensus (support for Raft, BFT, Tendermint to be added in the near future). All these are capable of running on normal enterprise-grade servers (can be tested on normal desktop machines too) that neither require any special or demanding hardware requirements or are power hungry.